# Python: Search for term#1, then search backwards for search#2 in file with multiple results

Tags: python, file, search

I have a file with text like this for example

"Name: John| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco FRUIT: APPLE
Name: Mike|  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in cu FRUIT: PEAR
Name: James| Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada. Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla. Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis. Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt. FRUIT: APPLE"

Once I load this file, I want to search for search term #1, for example, "APPLE"
Then search backwards for "Name" and then have it return the names.

So a search for "APPLE" would return John & James
A search for "PEAR" would return Mike

My file has a character like a | after the name to help determine what to grab.

I thought a regex would be appropriate but I'm not that familiar with them and not sure how to do 2 search terms.

In Python thanks

I've tried regex expressions but getting stuck on finding the correct syntax

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try formatting your question with the `{}` button to make verbatim input and output distinct from prose text. Also it is not fully clear what you are asking, please try eleborating more, maybe with a simpler and shorter example.

Comment: regular expressions are not used for those tasks. Regex used for much more complicated tasks. Have you tried a SQL language? there is integrated lib for python.